# Selecting columns not present in the dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I am creating a `dataframe` from an XML file. It has some information on a dealer, and then a dealer has multiple cars - each car is an sub-element of the `cars` element and is represented by a `value` element - each `cars.value` element has various car attributes. So I use an `explode` function to create one row for each car for a dealer like follows:

```py
exploded_dealer = df.select('dealer_id',explode('cars.value').alias('a_car'))
```

And now I want to get various attributes of `cars.value`

I do it like this:

```py
car_details_df = exploded_dealer.select('dealer_id','a_car.attribute1','a_car.attribute2')
```

And that works fine. But sometimes the `cars.value` elements doesn't have all the attributes I specify in my query. So for example some `cars.value` elements might have only *attribute1* - and then I will get a following error when running the above code:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'attribute2'
>   given input columns: [dealer_id,attribute1];"

How do I ask Spark to execute the same query anyway. but just return `None` for the *attribute2* if it is not present?

UPDATE I read my data as follows:

```py
initial_file_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='dealer').load('<xml file location>')

exploded_dealer = df.select('financial_data',explode('cars.value').alias('a_car'))
```

Comment: this is tricky since it is the SQL query that fails, not the python code. What surprises me is that usually, there is one schema for for a dataframe, and this schema can include or not the attribute. So either it is a bug, or you did something tricky to build your dataset. If yes, please specify. Anyway, what is interesting is that there is no equivalent of TRY in Spark SQL, I think. Which means that you would have to use a workaround, like forcing a schema with all attributes when creating the dataframe.

Comment: "What surprises me is that usually, there is one schema for a dataframe "- so the thing is: my code is static, so i can specify that always take columns a,b,c from the file, because i know that they are there and i only need those three columns. But one day there might be an xml with columns a, b, d - but i still need a, b, c only, even if it means that i get no data for column c. And because my code is static it will ask for a,b,c and because c is missing it would fail.

Comment: @Dennis I know it is not answer to your question, but it might help nonetheless: you could maybe make a logic that first get the schema and generate your query accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already make specific assumptions about the schema the best thing you can do is to define it explicitly with `nullable` optional fields and use it when importing data.

Let's say you expect documents similar to:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <objects>
            <object>
                <attribute1>...</attribute1>
                 ...
                <attributebN>...</attributeN>
            </object>
        </objects>
    </row>
</rows>
```

where `attribute1`, `attribute2`, ..., `attributebN` may not be present in a given batch but you can define a finite set of choices and corresponding types. For simplicity let's say there are only two options:

```
{("attribute1", StringType), ("attribute2", LongType)}
```

You can define schema as:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("objects", StructType([
    StructField("object", StructType([
      StructField("attribute1", StringType(), True),
      StructField("attribute2", LongType(), True)
    ]), True)
  ]), True),
  StructField("id", LongType(), True)
])
```

and use it with reader:

```
spark.read.schema(schema).option("rowTag", "row").format("xml").load(...)
```

It will be valid for any subset of attributes ({∅, {attribute1}, {attribute2}, {attribute1, attribute2}}). At the same time is more efficient than depending on the schema inference.